# Different content based on login

Tags: android, authentication

In my application I want to implement the possibility for the user to enter his name, surname, and another value. How can I store  this value, the name and surname locally? How can I retrieve these information later in my activities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How con I store locally this value, the name, and surname, and how can i retrieve these information later in my Activities?

[Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

A basic example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   String Name = settings.getString("user_name", "unknown");
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putString("user_name", mUserName);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.apply();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shared Preferences or SQLite database to store data.
Using Shared Prefereces : 
To store data

```
SharedPreferences s = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor e = s.edit();
                            e.putString("emp_no",e1.getText().toString());
                            e.putString("pn",e2.getText().toString());
                            e.commit();
```

To retrieve data

```
SharedPreferences s=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                en=s.getString("emp_no",null);
```

Using Sqlite Database

For this you need to make a class which extends SQLiteHelperClass. 
For more details refer this link 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm